# Tkinter Title Bar options

Tags: tkinter, editor, titlebar

Is there a way in Tkinter that I can edit the title bar and options such as background colors, foreground colors, title bar size. Here is my code for a class I am working on and I was looking for ways to make the title bar match the frame.

```
#CreateFile
from Tkinter import *

class CreateFile(Tk):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model=model
        myfont = ("Arial", 11, "bold")
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Create New File')
        
        self.resizable(0,0)
        frame = Frame(self,bg='black')
        self.lbl=Label(frame,text='Name: ',bg='black',fg='yellow')
        self.lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.file_entry=Entry(frame,width=30,font=myfont,bg='black',fg='yellow')
        self.file_entry.bind('<Control-a>',self.select_all)
        self.file_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.create_btn=Button(frame,text='Create',bg='black',fg='yellow')
        self.create_btn.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)    
        frame.grid()
        self.mainloop()
    
    def select_all(self,event):
        print 'd'
        
model=None
createFile = CreateFile(model)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't modify the attributes title bar.

Your only option is to turn off the titlebar completely (using `self.wm_overrideredirect(True)`) and then creating your own titlebar. This will require that you add your own bindings for moving and resizing the window.

Comment: This is perfectly fin i can take the time to do this. Do you know of any good tutorials or source code that could save me some time?